# Best way to synchronise data: MySQL -> SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

I have a fairly straight way to copy selective data using SQL like so:

```
# Courses
DROP TABLE db_node.courses;
CREATE TABLE db_node.courses LIKE db_prod.course_sis;
INSERT INTO db_node.courses SELECT
    *
FROM
    db_prod.course_sis
WHERE
    db_prod.course_sis.enabled = 1
AND db_prod.course_sis.hidden <> 1;
```

This is easy when I am on the same server with the same db, however I want to run this SQL to get put the final data on the SQL Server.

This isn't just a once off thing, it would need to be handled every hour or so. I am unable to change db's, one will always be MySQL and SQL Server because the data is used in a sharepoint app.

Thanks

Comment: SSIS sounds like a good fit for your requirement.

Comment: Is this similar to setting up MySQL as a connection from the SQL Server (Linked Server?), then letting SQL Server running the SQL?

Comment: Not exactly. It is an ETL tool, that lets you transfer data between heterogeneous platforms

Answer (score 1):

There are several third-party tools to make this transition easier. 
Check out SSMA [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/02/07/mysql-to-sql-server-migration-how-to-use-ssma.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/03/30/migrating-data-into-sql-server-using-ssma.aspx).
I'd also look at SQL Studio scheduled tasks to automate the process.

Comment: Perhaps I can filter it before hand and then it just needs to replicate the whole database over. I'll check into the docs, thanks.